# make textbox value another textbox with checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to assign a textbox value to another textbox when the checkbox is ticked. The values are not showing in the textbox when I click the checkbox.

```js
function filladdress() {
  var address1 = $("#delivery_address").val();
  var suburb1 = $("#delivery_suburb").val();
  var post1 = $("#delivery_postcode").val();
  var textbox = $("#same-address").attr('checked')

  if textbox.attr('checked', true)
  $("#billing_address").val(address1);
  $("#billing_suburb").val(suburb1);
  $("#billing_postcode").val(post1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Delivery Address</h2>
  <p>Address</p>
  <input id="delivery_address" type="text" name="delivery_address" />
  <p>Suburb</p>
  <input id="delivery_suburb" type="text" name="delivery_suburb" />
  <p>PostCode</p>
  <input id="delivery_postcode" type="text" name="delivery_postcode" />
</div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="same-address" value="checked">
  same as delivery address
</label>

  <h2>Billing Address</h2>
  <p>Address</p>
  <input id="billing_address" type="text" name="billing_address" />
  <p>Suburb</p>
  <input id="billing_suburb" type="text" name="billing_suburb" />
  <p>PostCode</p>
  <input id="billing_postcode" type="text" name="billing_postcode" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues with your current logic:

- You have an unnecessary `)` at the end of the JS.
- The `filladdress()` function is never called. Presumably you want to do this when the checkbox is changed.
- The `if` statement syntax is broken. Firstly you need to wrap the condition in parentheses. Secondly, you're using the setter of `attr()`, not the getter, so the condition would always equate to true due to type coercion of the resulting jQuery object.
- The is no `#same-address` element in the HTML. I assume this should be the checkbox itself.
- You're missing the opening `<div>` tags

Once you address all these issues, and add an unobtrusive event handler, the code should look something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $delAddress1 = $("#delivery_address");
  var $delSuburb1 = $("#delivery_suburb");
  var $delPostcode = $("#delivery_postcode");

  $("#same-address").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#billing_address").val($delAddress1.val());
      $("#billing_suburb").val($delSuburb1.val());
      $("#billing_postcode").val($delPostcode.val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2>Delivery Address</h2>
  <p>Address</p>
  <input id="delivery_address" type="text" name="delivery_address" />
  <p>Suburb</p>
  <input id="delivery_suburb" type="text" name="delivery_suburb" />
  <p>PostCode</p>
  <input id="delivery_postcode" type="text" name="delivery_postcode" />
</div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="same-address" id="same-address" value="checked">
  same as delivery address
</label>
<div>
  <h2>Billing Address</h2>
  <p>Address</p>
  <input id="billing_address" type="text" name="billing_address" />
  <p>Suburb</p>
  <input id="billing_suburb" type="text" name="billing_suburb" />
  <p>PostCode</p>
  <input id="billing_postcode" type="text" name="billing_postcode" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of your `if` statement is wrong, second there is nothing triggering the `filladdress` function

**Working demo**

```js
function filladdress() {
  var address1 = $("#delivery_address").val();
  var suburb1 = $("#delivery_suburb").val();
  var post1 = $("#delivery_postcode").val();
  

  if ($("[name=same-address]").prop('checked')) {
    $("#billing_address").val(address1);
    $("#billing_suburb").val(suburb1);
    $("#billing_postcode").val(post1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Delivery Address</h2>
<p>Address</p>
<input id="delivery_address" type="text" name="delivery_address" />
<p>Suburb</p>
<input id="delivery_suburb" type="text" name="delivery_suburb" />
<p>PostCode</p>
<input id="delivery_postcode" type="text" name="delivery_postcode" />
</div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="same-address" onchange="filladdress()" value="checked">
  same as delivery address
</label>

<h2>Billing Address</h2>
<p>Address</p>
<input id="billing_address" type="text" name="billing_address" />
<p>Suburb</p>
<input id="billing_suburb" type="text" name="billing_suburb" />
<p>PostCode</p>
<input id="billing_postcode" type="text" name="billing_postcode" />
</div>
```